# Emacs: How to automatically insert space after colon in cc-mode derivatives

Tags: emacs, cc-mode

Suppose I have this code:

```
{
  "type"  : "home",
  "number":"212 555-1234"
}
```

I want my emacs to automatically insert space after colon in some modes.

Particularly I'm using javascript-mode based on cc-mode. Can it help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be something like this (in your .emacs):

```
(defun my-js-hook ()
  (local-set-key ":" '(lambda () (interactive) (insert ": "))))

(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'my-js-hook)
```

More sophisticated alternatives include [yasnippet](http://yasnippet.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/index.html) or [skeleton mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SkeletonMode). They are probably overkill for something this simple, but are useful tools if you want more sophisticated templating.

EDIT: I'm not aware of any cc-mode magic that allows for different behaviour inside comments. I don't use cc-mode much, but I don't see anything obvious in the manual. Here's a bit of code that may do what you want though:

```
(defun my-js-hook ()
  (local-set-key ":" 
             '(lambda () 
                (interactive)
                (let ((in-comment-p))
                  (save-excursion
                    (setq in-comment-p (comment-beginning)))
                  (if in-comment-p 
                      (insert ":")
                    (insert ": "))))))
```

Comment: Thank you for replay. This looks good but will override behavior for comments too.  I asked specifically about cc-mode because I believe it can be done with some cc-mode magic (I believe they have something for that because the project exist since 1992)

Comment: you made my day :-) looks like it's somethings to start autoformat minor mode from =). But I don't understand this line: 
(save-excursion (setq in-comment-p (comment-beginning))). Why we can't initialize it in let?

Comment: `comment-beginning` moves point as a side effect. So it needs to be wrapped in `save-excursion`, otherwise the `:` will get inserted at the beginning of the comment. Maybe you could move the `save-excursion` into the let variable declarations? Try it out!